# Слово "рыпаться"

Tags: этимология

Я тоже об этимологии хочу спросить. А именно, о слове "рыпаться". Как оно образовалось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю комментарий Трубачева к Фасмеру:

> ры́паться •• ["беспокоиться, метаться", болг. ри́пам "мечусь, подпрыгиваю", чеш. vуrуроvаt "быстро шагать", польск. rурас́. Все – из rу-, ryti с суф. -р-, сюда же лит. rūpė́ti "заботить(ся)"; см. Трубачев, Этимологические исследования по русск. языку, 2, стр. 40. – Т.],

то речь идет о родственности рыпаться с "рыть" - словом, имеющим общеиндоевропейский генезис.

Answer (score 0):

В повторной теме удалил ответ, напишу его тут.

Я думаю, что был такой корень "рып/рип/реп", который имел значение "шип, острие". Отсюда же, возможно, такие слова, как "репей" (аналогия, думаю, понятна), "еРЕПениться" (буквально "покрываться колючками" или "воспринимать в штыки").

У Даля: РЫПЕТЬ, рыпнуть, южн. рыпать, скрыпеть, издавать скрып. Воз рыпит, дверь зарыпела, сапоги рыпять. Рып, скрып. Сапоги с рыпом, со скрыпом. Рыпучий, скрыпучий. На нозе сафьян рыпиць, а в борщу чорт кипиць, зап. т. е. пусто.

Тут "рыпеть" может трактоваться как "издавать резкий звук", а скРИП – звук, который режет слух.

В английском языке есть слова ripper (маньяк-потрошитель или острый инструмент для разрыхления), reaper (жнец как профессия или Жнец как Смерть с косой). Есть основания полагать, что этот корень действительно общеиндоевропейский.

В качестве полета фантазии слово "крепкий" можно понимать как "устойчивый к чему-то режущему".

Из всего это "рыпаться" можно понимать как "выставить наружу шипы, показать зубы, воспринимать в штыки".

В общем, моя версия такая.