# Происхождение слова "рыпаться"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Слово "рыпаться" (дергаться, пытаться освободиться) уже даже не подчеркивает Ворд. ))) А какова этимология этого слова? У меня даже версий нет.

Answer (score 0):

Повтор. 
Здесь:

[Слово "рыпаться"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10794)